# Shell script termination notification

Tags: shell

I have a requirement in shell script that in case if shell terminates for some reason I.e terminal closed or user terminated, I would like to do some work like clean up and unlocking etc. Is it possible? If so please explain how it can be done.
Thanks in advance,
Praveen P B

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible. Check for signal using `trap` command. See `help trap`.

**Example**

```
cleanup() {
    ...
    exit
}

trap cleanup SIGINT # user terminated
trap cleanup SIGHUP # terminal closed
trap cleanup SIGTERM # killed with kill -15
```

Comment: +1. Minor comment: Only SIGKILL or SIGSTOP cannot be caught. But SIGSTOP does not really kills the process, just stops it until a SIGCONT is received.

Answer (score 1):

What @Grzegorz said, is correct, but note the following:

- You didn't indicate the OS (and shell, but we assume `sh`), so to stay POSIXly correct you should use uppercase signal names (like `SIGINT`). Also see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/trap.html).
- Unless you want to let your script continue running, after receiving the signal, you should put `exit` as the last line in your "cleanup" function.
- Don't forget to manually call your "cleanup" function before exiting the script by other means (i.e. before "falling off" the end or whenever you manually call `exit`). Alternatively register a handler with `trap cleanup EXIT`.
- Note that you cannot catch `SIGKILL`, i.e. `kill -9 <mypid>` by this means (or any other means for that matter). So make sure you can somehow deal with the fact that cleanup may actually *not* happen. For example, check during your script initialization, whether old (orphaned) lock-files still exist and exit with an error, telling the user/admin to clean up manually. Now, differentiating between lock-files that legitimately exist and remains of a killed instance, might not be trivial and largely depends on your script. You could write the scripts PID into the lock-file, and then, if a lock-file exists when (another instance of) your scripts finds a lock-file make sure that the process with that PID still exists, if it does, chances are another script instance is truely running. Otherwise, manual cleanup might be necessary. But even that is not 100% fail safe.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer for POSIX compatibility and exit call.